# matlab gui, no clipping using scrollbar

Tags: matlab, user-interface, scrollbar, clip

I wanted to implement an scrollbar in my gui.
so I put a panel. then added a slider plus another panel as it's children and used the slider to change inner panel's position.
but when I scroll down, the contents of the inner panel go out of the outer panel. The outer one was supposed to clip inner panel's contents since I turned its "clipping" property on.
This is what exactly happens:
http://www.ukimagehost.com/view/d5e9b6b4207bf571.jpg

This is my fig file + m file:
http://esiei.persiangig.com/temp/ch1_out.zip

Comment: Can we see the code?  It's hard to discuss otherwise

Comment: scrollbar's callback is this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5603933/
and the fig file is a parent panel(tag = scrollable), a child panel (tag = pan) and a slider (tag = scrollbar) which is another child of the parent panel. "scrollbar" 's callback changes the position of "pan". "pan" is a child of "scrollable". so "scrollable" should clip outer parts of "pan". but it doesn't. I hope I haven't made it complicated!

Comment: It's still difficult to help without a proper code listing.  We need to see the code which creates and places the panels, and you should edit the question and put the code there.  Ideally, you should be providing code samples which other people can immediately run themselves - that makes it a lot easier to help.

Comment: I designed the panels with guide.it's all in the fig file so there's no code about panel design that I can put here. however I put the link to my fig file and m-file

Comment: I followed the second post on this page: http://www.mofeel.net/582-comp-soft-sys-matlab/31081.aspx
but simply the outer panel doesn't "clip" the inner's content!

Comment: after hours of searching, I found the same problem here: http://compgroups.net/comp.soft-sys.matlab/-hide-gui-uicontrol-using-slider/391646
seems like it has no solution!

Comment: I'm having the same problem! Even if I specified the clipping property on, it doesn't stop my 3D plot from expanding in other panels.